# What are all the other treasures in Odin's treasury?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, object-identification, thor-ragnarok

In Thor Ragnarok, Odin's treasury contains the tessaract, that-big-flame-guy's crown, the eternal fire, and a few other things that Hela walks past. What are those other things?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie, but I'm guessing there's tons of stuff. If so, then this is a bit too broad. Can you limit the scope or give a description of each item you want [identified](https://youtu.be/6ZWvWNgCyqg?t=16s)?

Comment: @mooz, there are only like two other items not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 7):

The Tesseract

Surtur's crown

The Eternal Flame

The Casket of Ancient Winters

and The Infinity Gauntlet

> which is fake

(will add in pictures later, unless someone else wants to add them in now)